# Want to move typing position to the end of the line if removing the last character and instantly replacing it C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I've got a textbox that resets back to 0 everytime you delete the last number in the textbox, but what makes this annoying is that when it replaces it; the cursor that you type with moves to the left of the 0, making anything you type afterwards have a 0 after it unless you click after the 0. Is it possible to make it so that when I delete the last digit, it goes back to the right of the newly replaced digit?

```
    private void iterations_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        resetToZero(iterations);
    }

    private void resetToZero(TextBox x)
    {
        if (x.Text == "")
        {
            x.Text = "0";
        }
    }
```

Comment: I would put the `0` in the textbox when it loses focus and does not have text. That way the `0` won't mess with typing. I would also use `SelectionStart` and `SelectionLength` to select the whole text when the textbox gets focus (addendum: perhaps only when it has `0`), so that you can start typing without worrying about the `0`. Although what I am saying, is more a concern of user experience than an answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put the cursor at the end of the text, you can just set the `SelectionStart` to `1`, which is right after the `0`, or more generically, you can use the length of the text box `Text` property:

```
private void resetToZero(TextBox x)
{
    if (x.Text == "")
    {
        x.Text = "0";
        x.SelectionStart = x.TextLength;;
    }
}
```

Or, to put the zero there and then select the text automatically, you can do do:

```
private void resetToZero(TextBox x)
{
    if (x.Text == "")
    {
        x.Text = "0";
        x.SelectionLength = x.TextLength;
    }
}
```

Comment: That second example looks very nice, will try it, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look into the TextBox.SelectionStart and TextBox.SelectionLength properties.